# How to update TDM GCC on windows using the web-installer?

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw, tdm-gcc

The feature list, states:

"It has an easy-to-use single-file installer that creates a working installation with just a few clicks, and can update that installation when new packages become available."

Great, but how to do the update? If I run the installer and "manage" my installation, nothing is updated at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was that I used the "[current installation]" option thinking, that this will update, well... my current installation. Which is wrong. It doesn't do anything.

So, you need to select on of the other options and it will download what you have selected.